# How can compute "Mean Absolute Error (MAE)" by CDO

Tags: cdo-climate, cdo.message

I did not find as a new student how to calculate  "Mean Absolute Error (MAE)" by CDO!
Can you assist us with how to compute by CDO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have your observations (or analysis?) in obs.nc and model in model.nc then you can calculate the MAE in the following way

```
# calculate the difference 
cdo sub model.nc obs.nc diff.nc   

# absolute value
cdo abs diff.nc abs.nc 

# time mean
cdo timmean abs.nc MAE.nc
```

or piping it all in one line:

```
cdo timmean -abs -sub model.nc obs.nc MAE.nc
```

If instead of the temporal mean you need the spatial MAE then of course you replace timmean with fldmean

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent kind help and well explained.
At the same time can I ask you one more question?
Like how to calculate the "Standard deviation" by CDO?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Khan. Please consider upvoting the question and accepting the answer. If you have further questions about CDO, it is better to post a new question. Comments are not suitable as you cannot post code

Comment: @RobertWilson I'm not entirely sure but I think new users are not able to upvote until they get to a certain amount of rep. But you can accept the answer with the green tick though Khan if you found the answer useful 